# How do DC solar optimizers work in series?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, series, solar-energy

Tigo and SolarEdge both have solar DC power optimizers. These have MPPT built in and optimize the panel. That is, the panel gis connected to them, then the optimizers are hooked up in series to each other.  They also follow the NEC and allow remote shutdown at the panel of course, so you're getting a two-fer.

In both cases I'm trying to understand how they can work in series based on assumptions that may be wrong:

1. They're using some sort of IC like those from ST that do MPPT at uA power levels with a boost/buck DC/DC converter and voltage and current sensors.
2. Somehow, without having the output from one fed into the input of the other, they're allowing series connection without having to size/spec this IC and MOSFETs to the total size of the array. (That is, the ST chip that I've seen works up to about 80 VDC at 15 A and you'd want to save money by using low power MOSFETs. If you hook 10x 500 W panels together, you're going to be in the 480 VDC range in series, so if they're actually running the input through with the solar cells and using a bypass FET then the buck still has to be able to handle the sum of the voltages of every panel/optimizer that came before which would be very expensive in your cost of FETs with at least 5 per optimizer.)

So as far as I can tell, either they've sized every DC optimizer so that the buck/boost can handle the total string array voltage (600 V!) and simply deciding when to bypass the panel entirely or to feed the previous panels into the string like a typical series solar panel connection - and they're somehow doing the MPPT on the buck/boost while receiving the input from the previous panel (probably easy to do with a voltage/current sense on the input from the previous panel subtracted from the total power through the attached panel.)

OR

They're doing something that I don't understand that allows them to have the buck/boost of the MPPT output series with the previous panel without the power from the previous panel having to go through the solar input and the buck/boost.

OR

Some 3rd option that I haven't thought of.

I considered that they might hook these up in parallel to each panel and create a mini DC bus for the string and then have a boost converter for the result that transmits the power to wherever it's going, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Is there a simple circuit design that allows the output of a synchronous buck/boost to be series with the output of a previous synchronous buck/boost without having to have the previous buck/boost's output run through the current buck/boost too?

(PS not interested in if you think these are a good idea, simply interested in how they function to create the series circuit as I can't find a circuit diagram online and I don't have one to look at.)

Comment: I assume that each converter is connected to a section of solar panel that is electrically isolated form the other sections. If the individual converters are not connected to earth or a common point, the internal components experience only the solar panel voltage and their own internally generated voltages. If the output common is grounded, any converter could experience the maximum output voltage with respect to ground, but they could be insulated for that.

Comment: _”either they've sized every DC optimizer so that the buck/boost can handle the total string array voltage (600 V!)”_ Too expensive. In case you loose regulation and the entire string tries to reverse the 600 V across that optimizer, it needs to bypass or clamp the voltage somehow. Luckily, the current is limited. I haven’t opened any but a depletion mode MOSFET or NC relay comes to mind.

Comment: @CharlesCowie so they’re tapping ground after the buck for the positive from the first optimizer?